# javascript url value to multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am building a form and all is going well except for the final part. I am trying to have a value carried from the URL into multiple fields i can get it into the first field but not the others.

Here is code from the form hopefully enough to see.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function populate() { //get the url variables
var varSection = window.location.search.substr(1);
var varArray = varSection.split("&")
for(var v=0; v<varArray.length; v++) {
var keyValueArray = varArray[v].split("="); //check the pair
}
 if(keyValueArray[0]=="id") { 
 varValue=keyValueArray[1]; 
 document.getElementById("QuoteID1[]").value=varValue; 
 }

}

</script>
</head>

<body style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" onLoad="populate()">

<form name="MakeQuote" method="post" action="QuoteProcess.php">
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr valign="top">
      <td height="34"><table width="960" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="40%" rowspan="4" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="49%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="11%">Weight</td>
          <td width="40%" class="right">QuoteID</td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Sand</td>
          <td><input name="Weight[]" type="number" id="Weight[]" size="8" maxlength="4" value="0.00"></td>
          <td>Kg                
            <input type="hidden" name="ProductID[]" id="ProductID[]" value="2">
            <input name="QuoteID1[]" type="number"  size="8" maxlength="8"  id="QuoteID1[]" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Shingle</td>
          <td><input name="Weight[]" type="number" id="Weight[]" size="8" maxlength="4" value="0.00"></td>
          <td>Kg                
            <input type="hidden" name="ProductID[]" id="ProductID[]" value="3">
            <input name="QuoteID1[]" type="number"  size="8" maxlength="8"  id="QuoteID1[]" value="" >
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Topsoil</td>
          <td><input name="Weight[]" type="number" id="Weight[]" size="8" maxlength="4" value="0.00"></td>
          <td>Kg                
            <input type="hidden" name="ProductID[]" id="ProductID[]" value="4">
            <input name="QuoteID1[]" type="number"  size="8" maxlength="8"  id="QuoteID1[]">
         </td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Mulch</td>
          <td><input name="Weight[]" type="number" id="Weight[]" size="8" maxlength="4" value="0.00"></td>
          <td>Kg                
            <input type="hidden" name="ProductID[]" id="ProductID[]" value="4">
            <input name="QuoteID1[]" type="number"  size="8" maxlength="8"  id="QuoteID1[]">
         </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          </form>
          </body>
          </html>
```

any help will be greatly recieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have multiple elements with the same ID. IDs are supposed to be **unique**. `getElementById` only selects the *first* element with that ID.

You can [select the elements by their name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) and iterate over them to set their value:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('QuoteID1[]');

for (var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = varValue;
}
```

---

FYI, you don't have to add `[]` to the IDs, they are only relevant in the `name`s of the elements, and only [if you are using PHP on the server side](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Comment: Also, if the controls have names (which they must to be sucessful and do in this case) then they usually don't need an ID at all.

Comment: the form is processed by php, i probly should have mentioned this sorry

Comment: @Voodoochile: I assumed so. Still, the `[]` are only relevant in the `name`s. You don't even need the IDs.